# Load JSON data into a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load a JSON file that creates a list inside a Bootstrap Modal. I have it set where if you click on a person's picture, the modal pops up.

```
<li class="project span3" data-type="pfa">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/anon.jpg" alt="Kenneth Atkins" />
        <h1>Kenneth Atkins</h1>
        <p>[Description here]</p>
    </a>     
</li>
```

Here's an example of the JSON data:

```
    var florida_exoneration = [
  {
    "last_name":"Atkins",
    "first_name":"Kenneth",
    "age":16,
    "race":"Caucasian",
    "state":"FL",
    "crime":"Sexual Assault",
    "sentence":"10 years",
    "conviction":2004,
    "exonerated":2008,
    "dna":"",
    "mistaken witness identification":"",
    "false confession":"",
    "perjury/false accusation":"Y",
    "false evidence":"",
    "official misconduct":"",
    "inadequate legal defense":"",
    "compensation":""
  }  
]
```

I'd like the modal to display something like this inside the box:

```
Title = "first_name + last_name"
Age = "age"
Race = "race"
State = "state"
""
""
```

I also want to make sure the data is tied to the picture so the modal doesn't get confused. I'm sorry if this is a bit confusing. I'll try and clarify if anyone has any questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Method 1: using Ajax**

Every time a user clicks an image, you get the id from the clicked image and then you send an Ajax request to server in order to get the JSON object.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="project span3" data-type="pfa">
    <a href="#" data-id="2" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/anon.jpg" alt="Kenneth Atkins" />
        <h1>Kenneth Atkins</h1>
        <p>[Description here]</p>
    </a>     
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
(function($) {
    var infoModal = $('#myModal');
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          url: 'getJson.php?id='+$(this).data('id'),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){ 
            htmlData = '<ul><li>title: '+data.first_name+'</li><li>age: '+data.age+'</li></ul>';
            infoModal.find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);
            infoModal.modal('show');
          }
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Method 2: using hidden div**

No need to any Ajax request, but you need to create a hidden div that contain all the information you want to display in the modal

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="project span3" data-type="pfa">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/anon.jpg" alt="Kenneth Atkins" />
        <h1>Kenneth Atkins</h1>
        <p>[Description here]</p>
        <div class="profile hide">
            <ul>
                <li>title: Atkins Kenneth</li>
                <li>Age: 16</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>     
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
(function($) {
    var infoModal = $('#myModal');
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function(){
        htmlData = $(this).find('.profile').html();
        infoModal.find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);
        infoModal.modal('show');
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```