# How to load data in 1 modal using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I made a HTML Table which contains data from database. If I click the Title of one table row, a modal should open which contains the data of the row.

For now i solved it this way:

```
<table>
{% for item in items %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{% for item in items %}
<div class="modal" id="modal{{ item.id }}">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <h5 class="modal-title">ID: {{ item.id }}</h5>
      ... 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is working now, no way. But as you can see, for each item in the array a modal will be created. So for example if I have 9000 Items in the array. I will have 9000 Modals in HTML. I guess thats not good so Im searching a way for using only 1 modal and including its content based on the ID.

How can I do this or what is the best way to do this using twig and PHP (not symfony framework, only twig engine) ?

I am using Bootstrap 4 for my Modal / Table.

EDIT:

@entio linked me to a similar Question, so I tried it out.
First I followed entio's Answer to encode my `$tickets` (the Array which contains all the data) to json:

```
{% autoescape %}
    var globalDataObject = {{ tickets|json_encode()|raw }};
{% endautoescape %}
```

The Json Object looks like this:

```
0:
    0: "93"
    1: "3"
    2: "Testticket"
    3: "0"
    4: ""
    5: "2017-12-08 14:43:21"
    6: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    7: "2017-12-08 14:43:21"
    8: "test"
    9: "Test"
    description: "test"
    subject: "Testticket"
    closed_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    closemessage: null
    device: "Test"
    customerid: "3"
    last_answer: "2017-12-08 14:43:21"
    opened_at: "2017-12-08 14:43:21"
    state: "0"
    ticketid: "93"
1:
    0: "94"
[...]
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to get access to this json Object.
The answer of entio's linked question doesn't help me out. My current Code (copy % paste with some changes of the linked answer):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {% autoescape %}
    var globalDataObject = {{ tickets|json_encode()|raw }};
    {% endautoescape %}

    (function($) {
    var myModal = $('#ticketModal');
    $('#subject').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'home.php?ticketid='+$(this).data('id'),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            htmlData = '<h1>Test:'+data.subject';
            myModal.find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);
            modal.modal('show);
          }
       });
       return false;
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The HTML Code of my Table Rows are changed to:

```
<td><a href="#" id="subject" data-id="{{ ticket.ticketid }}">{{ ticket.subject}}</a></td>
```

So the data-id for all the rows in the tabel are the database id's.
How I can search for the right Item in the Json now and open a Modal containing data from the json object ?

The current Javascript Code is not working. I guess it's because I never get access to the `globalDataObject`.

Comment: I'd solve it with JS. btw. what kind of modal is this? You could at least mention JS library you're using.

Comment: Seems op is using Bootstrap

Comment: Yea I am using Bootstrap 4 @entio

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna involve JS then you have to generate all the nodes.

Otherwise, you can just pass an object with all your data to JS and let it dynamically create modal on click event. Parsing to json can be done with json_encode filter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalDataObject = {{ yourDataObject|json_encode() }};
</script>
```

This is somewhat related so you can learn from it's answers:
[Load JSON data into a Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464562/load-json-data-into-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: Hm my DataObject is an Array: `$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE kundenid = :userid");
$result = $statement->execute(array('userid' => $userid));
$tickets = $statement->fetchAll();` using `{{ tickets|json_encode() }}` doesn't work for me (`Unexcpected & Token`)

Comment: did you dump your `tickets` to see what you got?

Comment: If i do `console.log({{ tickets }})` i will get the following output: `ƒ Array() { [native code] }`. Im not much familar with Javascript ^^

Comment: i mean twig dump or php var dump

Comment: Ah yea im getting this for example: `array(42) { [0]=> array(22) { ["ticketid"]=> string(2) "93" [0]=> string(2) "93` it continue.. And json_encode (PHP function) also works. but if I do your `var globalDataObject = {{ tickets|json_encode() }};` i get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` error.

Comment: you should edit your answer into: `<script type="text/javascript">
 {% autoescape %}
 var globalDataObject = {{ tickets|json_encode()|raw }};
 {% endautoescape %}
 
</script>` that worked for me.

Comment: Your linked Question wasn't helpful for me. But I guess encoding my array to json was a good first step. Now I need to search for how I can I pass the `id attribute of the <a>` to the javascript so if I click the link which has the `id="20"` the modal will open, searchin in json for the id 20 and if js found that then open the modal with the content of the json row which contains id 20 (name etc).

Comment: @KushGene And of course question was not helpful, but i guess you did scroll down to the answer, didn't you? Because the answer is precisely what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yea of course i scrolled down. But i guess the answer is "hardcoded" too. I need to create the HTML tag for each table row. (for each item in json then). So for now all is loaded into the json (encoded). Im not much familar with javascript. I didnt expected that I have to use javascript for solving my problem. I thought there is some way in PHP so I dont understand the example js code good.